# Divisors Combinations

Tags: combinations

Find the number of all the 3-digit numbers which are divisible by 2 but not divisible by 10.

I am totally confused here-- I was trying to sort out all numbers divisible by 2, and then cancel the ones divisible by 10. However there must be an easier way.

Comment: That's exactly how to do it.  But it's not hard in the least.

Comment: The smallest number divisible by $2$ is $100 = 50*2$. and the last is $998 = 2*499$.  The smallest number divisible by $10$ is $100=10*10$ and the last is $990=495*2$.  so.....

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how to do it but I'm not sure why you are being troubled by it.

How many even $3$ digit numbers are there?  Is that a hard question?  The first $3$ digit number is $100$ and the last is $999$.  The first even one is $100$ and the last even one is $998$.  Every other number is even. How many total are there?

How many $3$ digit numbers are divisible by $10$?  Same reasoning. The first $3$ digit number is $100$ and the last is $999$ and the first divisible by $10$ is $100$ and the last is $990$.  Every 10th number is divisible by $10$.  How many total are there.

And every number divisible by $10$ is even.  So just subtract the second answer from the first.

Comment: that is what I am trying to do, and I am getting 440-89= 351. However it is incorrect

Comment: Why are you getting $440$ and $89$?  There are $900$ three digit numbers.  Half of them are even and one tenth of them are divisible by $10$.

Comment: There are $1000$ numbers from $0$ to $999$. Exclude $1$ through $99$ and you have $900$ left.  Of those $1000$ numbers (including $0$) The even numbers run from $2*0=0$ to *under* $2*500=100$ so from $2*0=0$ to $2*499=998$. That's $500$ number.  but we start with $2*50=100$ and leave $2*0....2*49$ out. That leave $450$ even number. And the number divisible by $10$ are $10*0=0$ to $10*99=990$.  that's $100$ of them.  We leave out $0*10....9*10$ so thats $90$ with three digits.  So our answer is $450-90 = 360$.